# LOAD CSV with a collection using MATCH and FOREACH to form a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a CSV file that have information in the form:

```
Col1,Col2
A,B;C;D
```

I'm trying to generate relationships between A and each of B, C, D. In my particular case, B, C, D have already been created by importing another CSV file. Therefore, I do not need to create these nodes, but I do need to match them to get the node to form the relationship.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS line
WITH line

MERGE (a:Item {name: line.Col1})

FOREACH (x IN SPLIT(line.Col2, ';') |
  MATCH (s:Item {name: x})
  CREATE UNIQUE (s)-[:rel]->(a));
```

Nodes B, C, D have multiple properties, only one of which is in the second CSV, like:

```
B: {id: 123, name: B}
```

Is there a way to do this with Cypher? Currently, I get the error: "Invalid use of MATCH inside FOREACH". Using MERGE instead of MATCH results in new, unwanted nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `MERGE` instead `MATCH`:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS line
WITH line

MERGE (a:Item {name: line.Col1})

FOREACH (x IN SPLIT(line.Col2, ';') |
  MERGE (s:Item {name: x})
  MERGE (s)-[:rel]->(a));
```

If a `match` is more complicated, then you can first make a selection, and then walk on it:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS line
MERGE (a:Item {name: line.Col1})
WITH a, SPLIT(line.Col2, ';') as names
UNWIND names as x
MATCH (t:Item {name: x})
WITH a, collect(t) as sc

FOREACH (x IN sc |
  CREATE UNIQUE (x)-[:rel]->(a));
```

Comment: This didn't work in my case because I have multiple properties on the nodes being matched. I edited the question to reflect this missing part of the question.

Comment: @cannin I expanded my answer.